# Laravel Multi-Level SELECT on childern

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eager-loading, multi-level

I have two tables:

```
Table Section
id name section_id
1 Properties 0
2 Rent       1
3 Sale       2
4 Houses     2
5 Lands      2
```

and

```
Table Ads
id section_id ....
```

Sectoin Model

```
 class Section extends Model
    {
        public function Ads()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
        }
    
        public function SubSections()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Section::class);
        }
    
        public function Parent()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
        }
    }
```

Ad Model

```
class Ad extends Model
{
 
    public function Section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
    }


}
```

a `section` can have sub-sections and those sub-sections can have sub-sections , and so on and so forth, (you got the idea).

what am trying to do is load some ads let's say (10) out of all sections that are descendant of a section, so...

section`Properties` itself can have ads , and `Rent` by itself can has it's own ads, and it goes to it's descendant sections ...

what I have tried to do is use eager loading as follow:

```
$probs = Section::where('name', 'Properties')->first()->SubSections()->with('SubSections','Ads')->get();
```

it loads all the `sub-sections` of `sub-sections` , but not the `Ads`.

what I miss here!?

[image: a screenshot of the tables]

Comment: Are you sure **Properties** has **sub-sections** (say Rent) with ads? And do you really require **sub-sections of sub-sections** or just **sub-sections** with **ads**?

Comment: @prateekkathal sub-sections with ads would do it, but how would I still do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get everything

```
$section = Section::with('SubSections.Ads', 'Ads')->where('name', 'Properties')->first();

$sectionAds = $section->Ads;

$subSectionAds = $section->SubSections->filter(function($section) {
  return $section->ads->count() ? $section->ads : false;
})->flatten();

$allAds = $sectionAds->merge($subSectionAds);
```

### UPDATE

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652611/laravel-recursive-relationships), you can do something like...

```
public function SubSections()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Section::class);
}

public function AllSubSections($section == null)
{
  return $this->SubSections()->with('AllSubSections');
}

$section = Section::with('AllSubSections')->where('name', 'Properties')->get();

$subSections = $section->AllSubSections->flatten();

$subSectionsIds = $subSections->pluck('id')->toArray();

Ads::whereIn('section_id', $subSectionsIds)->get();
```

:)

Comment: @MixedCoder I asked this before also, Are you sure **Properties** has sub-sections (say Rent) with ads? Do you have any entry in `Ads` table where `section_id = (id of Rent Section)` ?

Comment: @MixedCoder - What happens when you do `dd($section->SubSections)`? Do you see Rent in `SubSections` key of the returned Model? In that if you see **Rent**, then do you find anything in the `Ads` Collection?

Comment: I see rent , but the Ads are empty collection.

Comment: @MixedCoder - Okay, so then obviously.... There are no ads inside rent. Can you send me a screenshot of your `sections` table and `ads` table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131821/discussion-between-mixedcoder-and-prateekkathal).

Comment: it only returns the subsections of `Proprieties` , not all the subsections of the subsections