# How do i get nested deep relationship to array in Laravel ( Situation is bit different than auto suggested answers)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I need to fetch and show multilevel categories in a selectbox.
So i have table called

`Categories`

`id          parent_id           name`

I am fetching collection in array form like this

```
 $categories = App\Category::where('parent_id','0')->with('children')->get()->toArray();
```

`children` - i have defined relationship in `Model` like this -

```
  public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }
```

So in my result set i am getting only one level relationship data ... If i want more than one levels the i need to do something like this -

```
 $categories = App\Category::where('parent_id','0')->with('children.children')->get()->toArray();
```

So writing 2 times `children` it gives me desired result but what if i have more than 2 or more?

How do i get that hierarchy?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654139/3226121)

Comment: Yes. This works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help