# Laravel - How to avoid N+1 problem when loading more results in blade?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a website that has submissions, and these submissions have comments. These comments are structured a lot like how reddit's are. Here is an image for reference:

[image]

These comments have a lot of relationships (has the auth user saved/upvoted/downvoted the comment, does the comment have children, who created the comment).

So to avoid a bunch of unnecessary server queries, I eager load these relationships.

```
$comments = Comment::with(['children','owner','savedComments','votes'])
                    ->where('submission_id', $submission->id)
                    ->where('parent_id', NULL)
                    ->orderBy('removed','asc')
                    ->orderBy($sortBy, $direction)
                    ->paginate(200);
```

And then I `foreach` these comments in the view. However, notice in my query that I only load parent comments.

For children, I load them in with a `foreach` through the comment's `children` relationship.

**Comment.php:**

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','parent_id')->orderBy('total_score', 'desc');
}
```

**comment_block.blade.php:**

```
@foreach ($comment->children as $comment)
    @if ($loop->depth == 10)
        <div>
            <a href="{{ route('get.submission', ['subchan' => $submission->subchan, 'id' => $submission->id, 'URLtitle' => $submission->URL_title,'commentID' => $comment->parent_id]) }}">Continue this thread</a>
        </div>
        @break
    @elseif ($loop->iteration == 8 && $totalComments >= 25) 
        <div class="loadMoreReplies"
        data-submission-id="{{ $submission->id }}"
        data-parent-id="{{$comment->parent_id}}"
        >Load More Replies (<span id="remaining-reply-count-{{$comment->parent_id}}">{{ $loop->remaining + 1 }}</span>)</div>
        @break      
    @else
        <div class="comment-container comment-container-child" id="comment-container-{{$comment->id}}">
            @include('partials.comment_block')
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

The problem with this is that despite the parent comment relationships being eager loaded, every single child comment is causing a query as well because they're being loaded in the view through a relationship. So my total server queries increases from one to potentially hundreds.

How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:**

For those that say I don't have an n+1 problem, these are my queries when I don't load child comments:

[image]

And this is when I do load child comments: 
[image]

I also use the [laravel query detector](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-query-detector) package, which is most certainly telling me that I have an n+1 problem.

Comment: I may be wrong, but every single child comment is not causing a new query, the query is only one, when you do `Comment::with(['children',...])`. All the child comments are already there when you do the foreach in the view.

Comment: as @porloscerrosΨ said, you don't have any n+1 problem

Comment: They are for sure. I log my queries in appserviceprovider. I get an extra query for every single child comment (so in my case 155). But if I remove the @foreach ($comment->children as $comment) block and only load the parent comments, my queries go down to 1. This is what the queries look like: https://i.imgur.com/Wvz6Gu3.png

Comment: @FelixMaxime can you point out which line in the blade view you are suspecting to execute an extra query?

Comment: @CaddyDZ All of the child comment relationships, but not the parent comment relationships. This is my alert when adding child comments: https://i.imgur.com/5INCTqp.png

Comment: @FelixMaxime I can't reproduce your problem after copy pasting your code to a test Laravel app on my machine

Comment: Recursive relationships require a large amount of custom logic to handle efficiently, as you need a way to do something like `->with(["children.children.children...."])` dynamically. I've done a solution, but I don't think it can be applied to your logic. I'd do some googling for how to handle recursive relationships in Laravel, and see if any of the results can give you some insight. This is probably a little too broad of a question currently though.

Comment: @TimLewis doing something like with(['children.children.children.children.children.children.children', actually does reduce the number of queries, but not by that much. I'd also need to eager load the children children children's saved comments, votes, etc. That would be a gigantic query.

Comment: Well, you'd have to do a `.children` for each nested level, as well as `children.owner`, `children.savedComments`, `children.children.owner`, `children.children.savedComments`, etc. etc. Constructing that manually is a no-go as it could have infinite levels of recursion, which is why you need to find a way to handle dynamically.

Comment: @TimLewis is there any way I could load all of the other relationships of the child within the children() relationship of the comment model?

Comment: I think so; try adding a `->with()` clause to `public function children()`; see if that reduces the queries.

Comment: It does! However, I can't do ->with('children') to the children() function, so my query count is still huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there's no way to eager load nested relationships in a recursion with Laravel, or at least not in this circumstance (tried asking in multiple places, not just stackoverflow).

So to solve my problem, I'm going to load all the parent comments and their relationships the normal way, but only load the child comments as data then fill them in with an AJAX call. This will only add one server query.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the answer on this question help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652611/laravel-recursive-relationships This was what I followed for my implementation for recursiveness between the same model, with some QOL modifications.

Comment: @TimLewis trying this just gives me a  ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Hmm, not sure why that would be; it was complicated, but I was able to implement the solution from the first link. And yeah; I'm not sure what that second link is doing; seems odd though. The ajax approach is fine tbh; might not be the smoothest UX if you have to do a new call to get each level of recursion, but would be decently efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What is your database?
Recursive data can be optimized into a single query if your DB supports common table expression.
However Laravel doesn't support those. You will have to create raw query.

If your DB does not support CTE (common table expression), then the best you can do is to load each level of recursion separately @Tim Lewis comment to @Felix Maxime answer covers that use case very well.