# How to query descendants of a model in Laravel and Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a category model with `parent_id` column which enables it to have or don't have children. The problem arises when I want to edit the parent of a category, and I want to exclude the **children of children** in edit form.

For example, I have following categories:

```
Category    Parent
cat1        no parent
cat2        cat1
cat3        cat2
```

How can I write a query with **Eloquent** to exclude `cat3` and other **descendants** in edit form?

Optimizing number of queries matters.

Comment: This type of relationship is not recursive by default, meaning that `Category::with('children')->first()` will return `cat1` and `cat2`, but not `cat3` (or any of it's descendants), as those are not immediate children of `cat1`. Might be worthwhile to show your relationship/query for getting `cat1`. (This is of course assuming you have defined a `children` relationship... If you haven't, that's a good place to start)

Comment: @TimLewis doing `Category::with('children')->first()` can return `cat3` with an empty `children` table.

Comment: Well yeah, but only if `cat3` is the result of `->first()` (order based off of ID). You'd need additional logic to query for a specific `Category`, like the answer below shows)

Comment: @TimLewis How can I write a recursive query to get all descendats? I write something like what you have mentioned (`Category::with('children')->first()`) for getting first children of a category.

Comment: That's a much larger question... Recursive relationships are complicated, requiring nested `->with()` logic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652611/laravel-recursive-relationships for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a children relation in the category model

```php
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

And a scope to get only parentless categories (master categories)

```php
public function scopeMasterOnly($query)
{
    return $query->whereNull('parent_id');
}
```

Then just use them to get the master categories and their children

```php
$categories = Category::query()->masterOnly()->with('children')->get();
```

Comment: Shouldn't need `::query()` there, `Category::masterOnly()->with('children')->get();` should work fine (I think)

Comment: @TimLewis not using `query()` lead to the model class using `query()` down the line anyway, it's just faster and good for IDE detection of methods ^^

Comment: I want to query other categories even if they are children of other categories rather than `cat1`. How can I do this?

Comment: @N69S Oh nice, good to know! It looks a little messier, but if it has purpose, then all's good :)

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI this code will get you (from your example) `cat1` and `cat2` inside of the array `children` in `cat1`