# Laravel Category Tree - Order Children

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a Laravel project with Categories and Children - I've got this function in my model:

```
    public static function tree() {
        return Category::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();
    }
```

Which I then call with
`$categories =  Category::tree();`

And on the view I have:

```
@foreach($categories as $index => $category)
   {{ $category->title }}
   @foreach($category['children'] as $child)
      {{ $child->title }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

That works fine - but I'm trying to sort the children alphabetically now.

I've tried this:

```
public static function tree() {
        return Category::with([implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')) => function($query) {
            $query->orderBy('title', 'ASC');
        }])->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();

    }
```

I've also tried `return Category::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->orderBy('title)->get();` but that just orders to parent categories.

But it doesn't sort them. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

--EDIT--

Following Tim's suggestion on a better way, I now have:

```
    public function children() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');

    }  
    
    public function childrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->children()->with('childrenCategories');
    }
```

Then...

```
       $categories =  Category::with(['childrenCategories' => 
            function($query) {
                $query->orderBy('title', 'ASC');
            }])->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();
```

Which works, but not the ordering part. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh my... does this do what I think it does? `with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))` equates to `children.children.children.children.children. ...` Cause if so, that's a very... odd approach to infinite depth recursive relationships.

Comment: I picked up the code a while back to be honest and it worked at the time but we're coming around to updating. I have been looking at some Laravel packages like https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset which may be a better solution

Comment: Haha yeah, I understand the legacy code acquisition reasoning :P For reference, the approach I use to recursive relationships is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654139/3965631. Basically, a single call to `Model::with('allChildren')` will, when setup properly, load all relationship depths. It _should_ allow for properly sorting on child models too (which is the core of your question; this was just a rather long tangent on approach)

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll take a look.

Comment: I've given it a go, and it works, but it's not sorting still :( Edited my post to add it on.

Comment: Nice :) But yeah, I think what you have wouldn't apply sorting beyond a single iteration. Something like `public function childrenSorted() { return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->orderBy('title'); }`, followed by `public function childrenCategoriesSorted(){ return $this->childrenSorted()->with('childrenCategoriesSorted'); }` _should_ work. It's a little more verbose and somewhat duplicated, but might work.

Comment: Ah yes. That worked. I _may_ still look at a nesting package in the longterm but this has sorted it for now. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent :) And yeah, that sounds like a good idea! I looked a bit more at the `nestedset` package, and it seems like it has some pretty useful stuff in it. But glad I could help regardless. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance, you can try to [sort](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby) your subcollections right in the view.

```php
@foreach($category['children']->sortBy('title') as $child)
  {{ $child->title }}
@endforeach
```

**But it is a very, very, very bad solution!**

Good way starts with reorganisstion of the whole structure of categories. I prefer nested set. There is a pretty cool implementation for Laravel.
https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Comment: Thanks. It's legacy code - but I'm coming to the realisation that it probably needs to be re-worked. I've seen this- github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset but I'll take a look at baum too. Thanks.