# Laravel withCount of all comments and child comments

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, count, nested

I am using Laravel 8 and the `withCount` attribute to get the amount of all comments which are published on my products model. Those comments have child comments as well. Now I would like to get the amount of published comments and child comments for each product...

My comment table:
`id, page_status_id, user_id, commentable_type, commentable_id, content`

My child comments table:
`id, page_status_id, user_id, comment_id, content`

This is my `comments` relation in my `product` model:

```
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable')->orderBy('id');
    }
```

And this is my `withCount` function:

```
    public function publishedComments()
    {
        return $this->comments()->where('page_status_id', PageStatus::getIdByStatus('publish'));
    }
```

It is very easy to get the count of published comments... but how do I get the count of all published comments AND child comments for a product?

Any ideas? I tried a raw SQL statement with `inner join` but that is also the wrong way..

Kind regards and thank you

Comment: can you use another query? i can tell you a query that gets what you need. but needs a seprate query

Comment: what do you mean? post an example pleas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build a recursive relationship query.
In a recursive query, you're trying to select all children plus their descendants. An example of this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654139/6212294) for eloquent.

As you are trying to count the children of children, you need to access the descendants.
In below code, I am trying to query relationship recursively by (`allComments`) function. It means, you can get all parent and children comments. Here, you are creating a recursive function by calling `with` and passing the `allComments` method.

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable')->orderBy('id');
}

public function allComments()
{
    return $this->comments()->with('allComments');
}
```

You can accompany `allComments` with relationship count like `Product::withCount('allComments')`

Comment: I cannot follow your answer.. Can you post a more detailed answer please?

Comment: yes for sure, but tell me the ambiguity about the answer.

Comment: You are using `->with('allComments')` which means `allComments` needs to be a relationship, right?!? But you haven't defined this relationship?

Comment: Answer has been updated. A link was provided for further clarifications.