# Create an array with nests using category.parent_id

Tags: laravel, nested

I created a table for the categories in the database.

parent_id (if root = null)
name
description

I have created functions for the Category model:

```
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    // recursive, loads all descendants
    public function childrenRecursive()
    {
        return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
    }
```

I need to create a recursive function that will return an array (not a collection) with a tree of these categories (id and name).

I can't deal with this problem. Can I ask you for help?

I return the collection by asking:

```
$categories = Category::with('childrenRecursive')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Recursive Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652611/laravel-recursive-relationships)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper method on your `Category` model. Utilize Higher Order Function and you should have a one liner in your controller.

```
public function toSimpleArray() {
   $arr =[
       'id' => $this->id,
       'name' => $this->name,
   ];

   if ($this->childrenRecursive->count() > 0) {
       $arr['children'] = $this->childrenRecursive->map->toSimpleArray()->all();
   }

   return $arr;
}
```

On your `$categories` collection you can now do. This will be an array representation as you wanted. I would personally always choose objects and collections.

```
$categories->map->toSimpleArray()->all();
```